# Custom animation: where to get the "from" value?

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm implementing a custom animation on a custom type (inherits from AnimationTimeline). As I'm using the animation inside VisualStateManager, I can't use the From property - so I didn't even bother to create it. But I do have a To dependency property.

Now, inside GetCurrentValue() I have three parameters, and I counted on using the first one ("defaultOriginValue") as the original value of my animated property. Apparently, it's not the original value but the default value (as specified in FrameworkProperyMetadate for the animated property).

How do I get the actual property value to animate from?

Comment: Just checked this again. My custom animation gets the *current value* of the property in `defaultOriginValue`. Maybe you post the code of your custom animation class.

Comment: And why do you think you can't use a `From` property in a VisualState?